# Triangle Hypotenuse

Tags: geometry

if the 2 triangles ABC and BCD in the image i provided shared the same Hypotenuse which is BC and it's length is 5, and the Hypotenuse opposite angle is 90, are the two triangles always share the same properties ?

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmJDI.png)

Comment: If the figure can be inscribed in the square on base CD, then it is solvable. You should indicate that in your question if it is part of the setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily. In your image, $ABC$ is a 3-4-5 triangle, and $BCD$ *looks* like one too, but all we really know about $BCD$ is that its hypotenuse is 5 and it has a right-angle. It could be another 3-4-5 triangle, or it could be an isosceles right-triangle with catheti of length $5/\sqrt{2}$, or countless others. You'd need to know one of the other sides or angles of $BCD$ to be able to fully describe it.

Comment: "Catheti"? I'm not familiar with that word. Does it mean "legs"?

Comment: It means exactly that; as far as I'm aware it's usually only used in the context of right-angled triangles.

Comment: please take a look at this image here, according to your answer there is no way we can find the square i added CDFE area, correct ?  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzr6DZ6Pthx_amQ1SHF0aHJaRkE/view

Comment: The fact that it fits precisely in a square adds new information that was not in the original picture, so no, the answer does not mean that. With the new information, we might be able to say more.

Comment: Given that the entire figure can be inscribed in the square on base CD, we can find that angle BCD = arctan(13/16). From there, the rest of the figure is solvable.

Comment: The area of the square is 256/17